# How can I solve this problem?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, system-settings

I bought a new laptop with Ubuntu operating system. I started to configure the system and then I got the following error:

```
tail: can't open '/var/log/installer/debug': Premission denied
tail can't open '/var/log/syslog': No such file or directory
tail: no files
```

[image]

I can't close the system settings window now and the skip button isn't available.

Translation of the text on the screenshot:

The title bar says: System Setup

Heading in the window: Help and support

The main text: The official documentation will explain the general aspects of Ubuntu. It is available both online and by calling throug the Help icon on the panel. On Ask Ubuntu, you can ask a question or search through an extensive collection of ready-made answers to questions. Support in your native language can be provided by the local community team. Links to other useful resources are located in the Community Support or Commercial Support section.

Text written above the errors: Opening the recording program

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What does configure the system mean? What did you do exact commands. Need a lot more details for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: @David, Ubuntu version - 20.04.1, my system settings window is frozen, the loading line is stuck in one place and I have the above mentioned error in Opening the recording program. In general, the computer is working, but this window does not close and resrating does not help. Also I don't have any desktop shortcuts and button with 9 dotts.

Comment: It would be useful to have a screenshot of this window that won't close. It's hard to tell what exactly you are doing. If you can't add a real screenshot, try to photograph the relevant portion of the screen, upload the image to imgur.com, edit the question and include a link to the image.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to reflect the actual problem. This site is mainly aimed at users looking for solutions, and therefore, it is important that the question titles are hinting to the problem. In addition, elaborate on your problem to clarify: it is currently impossible to understand what you did, when you get that message and what dialog you cannot skip.

Comment: What recording program? Your question needs DETAILS!

Comment: I was wondering about the "button with 9 dots" as well.

Comment: @Jos, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FW4hb244hj2Tsfqfa5KrvlJ1vk5lFqPR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jos, i can't register on imgur.com, because I'm from another region.

Comment: @Jos, try it now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FW4hb244hj2Tsfqfa5KrvlJ1vk5lFqPR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You will need to translate this text for us - this is an English language site.

Comment: @Jos, The first heading: System Setup, the second heading: Help and support, the main text: The official documentation will explain the general aspects of Ubuntu. It is available both online and by calling throug the Help icon on the panel. On Ask Ubuntu, you can ask a question or search throug an extensive collection of ready-made answers to questions. Support in your native language can be provided by the local community team.  Links to other useful resources are located in the Community Support or Commercial Support section. Text written above the errors: Opening the recording program

Comment: No please really, add this to your question. This is essential information. Comments may get cleaned up occasionally.

Comment: @new_user When did this window appear? You said you bought a laptop with Ubuntu installed. Did this appear when you first started the computer? Maybe the system hasn't been (pre)installed correctly and it would be easier just to install the system again by yourself...

Comment: It looks like a (serious) bug in the installer. At this point you probably don't have a `sudo` account yet, so there is no way to correct the permission errors. However, you could always abort the installation and install Ubuntu by yourself, as @raj suggests.

Comment: @raj, yes it appeared when I started the computer for the first time.

Comment: @Jos, can you tell me or give me a link to the guide how to abort installation and install Ubuntu by myself ?